# Using MorphMap for multiple keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a polymorphic model, Attachment, which is linked to another model, Product, which hasMany attachments.

Attachments can be images or axonometries, therefore in the "attachable_type" column of the attachment, I need to have both "product_image" and "product_axonometry" as relationship identifier.

Within the morphMap in the AppServiceProvider I did this:

```
    Relation::morphMap([
        'product_image' => 'App\Product',
        'product_axon' => 'App\Product',
    ]);
```

But it only seems to recognize the first array element, product_image. The product_axon is not registered as relationship.

So how to tell Laravel even this last field identifies a morphMany relationships between the two models? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not possible to have multiple keys for the same model.

Comment: I would think you would have something like `Relation::morphMap([
        'product_image' => 'App\Product_Image',
        'product_axon' => 'App\Product_Axon',
    ]);`  But if they are both a `Product` model, I'm not sure you need to use a polymorphic relationship yet -- seems like `Attachments` could just have a `product_id`.

Comment: I solved inserting a new column...